# find a partial string with regex as well in an HTML doc (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I want to find a sentence in an HTML doc. I know how it begins and ends but it could have different words/characters in the middle. Is it possible to use a combination of string and regex and then string?

```
const stringBegin = 'The film was';
const regex = /[AZaz09_]/g;
const stringEnd = 'in London';
$('p:contains(stringBegin,regex,stringEnd).text();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this would work for you:

```
var html    = $('html').text();
var matches = html.match(/The\sfilm\swas(.*)in\London/mi);
```

`matches[0]` will contain the whole matching text.

`matches[1]` will contain the text between 'The film was' and 'in London' (you might want to use *matches[1].trim()*, to remove starting and ending whitespaces).

Answer (score 1):

You can use a single regular expression to make the match, however your bigger problem is that you cannot use it with a `:contains` selector. Instead you can use `filter()` to provide a function with the logic to check each individual element. Try this:

```js
var re = /The film was \w+ in London/gi;
var $p = $('p').filter(function() {
    return re.test($(this).text());
});

// do something with $p here...
$p.addClass('foo');
```

```css
.foo { color: red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>The film was shot in London</p>
<p>The film was shot in California</p>
<p>The film was produced in London</p>
```

Also note the use of `\w` in the regex, which is a shorter form of the character set you originally had.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex pattern: `/The film was .* in London./g`

Comment: Can i use const or variables instead of of the string e.g. stringBegin instead of 'The file was'? i.e. /stringBegin .* stringEnd/g

Comment: You can write it as following:

Comment: var pattern = /stringBegin + regex + stringEnd/g;
and then make a regex search using the pattern variable you just created.